# Show that if $u_n + u_{n+1} \sim \dfrac{1}{n}$ then $u_n \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Saw this question in my textbook : Let $(u_n)$ be a real decreasing sequence such that : 
$$u_n + u_{n+1} \sim \dfrac{1}{n}$$
Show that $(u_n)$ converges to $0^{+}$ and give a simple sequence equivalent to $(u_n)$ 
My attempt : for every $\epsilon > 0$, we have for every $n\ge N $ :$$2u_n < u_n + u_{n+1} \le |u_n +u_{n+1}|\le \epsilon$$
It seems like I need to show that the terms of this sequence are all positive for this to work, I just don't know how to procede.

Comment: If it is decreasing, the first inequality is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $n_0$ such that $u_{n_0}<0$, this implies that for every $n>n_0, u_n\leq u_{n_0}$, we deduce that if  $n>n_0, |u_n+u_{n+1}|>2|u_{n_0}|$. Take $N$ such that $N>n_0$ and ${1\over N}\leq {{u_{n_0}}\over 4}$. For $n>N$,

$|u_n+u_{n+1}-{1\over n}|\geq 2|u_{n_0}|-{1\over n}\geq 2|u_{n_0}|-{{u_{n_0}}\over 4}={3\over 4}u_{n_0}$. Contradiction.

Since the sequence it positive and decreasing, it as a limit $l$, and $lim(u_n+u_{n+1})=2l=lim {1\over n}=0$ implies that $l=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$(u_n) $ is decreasing, so to prove it converges, you just need to show that

$$(\exists m\in\Bbb R)\;: (\forall n\in\Bbb N)\; u_n\ge m$$

Assume that

$$(\forall m\in \Bbb R)\;(\exists N\in\Bbb N) \;:\; u_N<m$$

then
$$(\forall n\ge N)\; u_n\le u_N<m$$
and with $m=-1$,
$$(\forall n\ge N)\; u_n+u_{n+1}<-2$$

thus $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(u_n+u_{n+1})\ne 0$$
but
$$u_n+u_{n+1}\sim \frac 1n$$

Finally, if we put $$\lim u_n=L$$
we will have
$$L+L=0\; and\; L=0^+$$

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition on non-negativeness of the terms of $u_n$ is correct, since if $u_{n_0}<0$ for some $n_0$ then
$$
u_n+u_{n+1}<2u_{n_0}\implies u_n+u_{n+1} \not\sim{1\over n}\quad,\quad n>n_0
$$